# Have <body> div cover entire width of the browser

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to have a background-color black div on my website, but for some reason, it does not extend across the entire width of the browser. I tried setting `width: 100%` but it only helped cover the right part of the website, and the left is still not covered.

If you run the code (I outlined the borders of the divs), you can see a gap between the red and green border on the left side.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="blackrect"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

body{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height:500px;
    width: 100%;

}

#blackrect{
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **margin: 0;** to you body;

In cases like this, use your browser inspector to find out what is causing the problem.

```css
html {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}

body{
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#blackrect{
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="blackrect"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was putting `margin:0px;` in the body css.